# Proving an inequality in real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How to show that the following inequality is true for all $x\in (0,\infty)$?
$$x10^{\frac{x}{2}}\ln{2.5}<5^x-2^x$$

My Try:

Let $a = \ln{2.5}$ then the left hand side is 
\begin{align*}
ax10^{x/2} & = axe^{\frac{x}{2}\ln{10}} \\
& = ax\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\ln{10} + \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\ln{10}\right)^{2}+\cdots \right) \\
\end{align*}
And, similarly we can extend the right hand side by using the series expansion of the exponential function but at the end it did not help me at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inequality says 
$$ x \ln(5/2) < \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{x/2} - \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{x/2}$$
Now the right side can be written as $$ \exp\left( \frac{x}{2} \ln(5/2)\right) - \exp\left(-\frac{x}{2} \ln(5/2)\right) = 2 \sinh\left(\frac{x}{2} \ln(5/2)\right)$$
so this is a special case of 
$$ t < \sinh(t) $$
which is true for all $t > 0$.  Note that the two sides are equal at $t=0$, 
their derivatives are equal at $t=0$, and
$$ \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} t = 0 < \sinh(t) = \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \sinh(t) $$

Comment: Wow didn't think of $\sinh$ at all, nice answer, +1

Comment: Interesting! I was completely off from thinking a use of hyperbolic function. I know it is true that $x<\sinh{x}$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, but would you mind giving me the reference?